# Link click and button click in one HTTP request

Tags: php, http, post, get, request

I was developing on my localhost and came across this question.

Consider there is such HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">
</form>

<a onclick="clickButton('submitButton');" href="guestbook/index.php?pageNumber=1">
```

The `<a>` click triggers submit button click event. The Javascript function looks like this:

```
function clicktButton(id) {
  if (id != "")
    document.getElementById(id).click(); // this will trigger the click event
}
```

My question is: is something like this possible? To send a HTTP request with link press and button press simultaniously?

Because by pressing an `<a>` link I already send a HTTP request with `$_GET['pageNumber']` parameter. But I also want to send the `$_POST['submitButton']` data at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is possible, but not so much with the code I see before me..

```
<form action="guestbook/index.php?pageNumber=1" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">
    <input type="button" name="submit">
</form>
```

This would essentially post the contents of the form, with a get request attached.

An `<a>` would not really work, because it generates a new HTTP request and would presumably skip JavaScript execution of the currently loaded page.

On the other hand, you can simulate the effects of an `<a>` click with JavaScript, by making a post request with the form data to `guestbook/index.php?pageNumber=1`. But if you do this I would recommend [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) as it will make things easier for you by adding this to the click event.

```
$.ajax({
    url:   "guestbook/index.php?pageNumber=1",
    data:  {'field':'value'},
    async: false
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply! I see... I guess I will have to make changes to my code then...I'm thinking of putting the POST data into additional GET parameter, like this `guestbook/index.php?pageNumber=1&activeFilter=data`. (the $_POST data just holds the table column name for filter, so it's nothing secure).