# How do I redirect to same page on submitting a form in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal with form which is getting called from a link in my parent home page :

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Contact</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" action="student.php"  target="_parent">
    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name = "name">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    <label class="mr-sm-2 sr-only" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Profession</label>
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="profession">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="1">Student</option>
        <option value="2">Parent</option>
        <option value="3">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail" name = "email">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="mr-sm-2 sr-only" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Type</label>
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="type">
        <option selected value="1">Feedback</option>
        <option value="2">Grievance</option>
        <option value="3">Admission</option>
        <option value="4">Other</option>
      </select>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Write..</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP code in my parent page to handle data of my modal form.

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $type = $_POST["type"];
        $profession = $_POST["profession"];
        $message = wordwrap($message,70);
        $headers = "From:".$email;
        $subject = "Message by".$name." ".$profession."of type".$type;
        mail("yashboura303@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";
    }
?>
```

Now I want to go back to home.php after submitting my modal form so that I can used mail() function to send mail. How can I achieve this? 
I obviously used "action=home.php" in form which is not working and tired "data-dismiss='modal' " in submit button tag but it's not actually submitting the form it's just closing the modal.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/355105/11700321

Comment: @EGC but how do I call this php as post request on button click?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39307462/11700321

Comment: @EGC by this method i can get my form data only through jquery right? Can I use php 'get' or 'post' to get data ?